# How to schedule back and front-end developers based on story points?

Tags: scrum, agile, planning, estimation, resource-planning

We are used to create multiple *sub-tasks* for each *user story* and provide each *sub-task* with an **estimate** in hours and assignee (**back** or **front-end**).

With the following outcome:

- Total **estimated** time needed in hours for *user story* divided over **back** and **front-end**
- The availability of both **back** and **front-end** developers can be taken into account when user stories are placed in sprints
- Developers are scheduled accordingly in [Harvest Forecast](https://www.getharvest.com/forecast/harvest-and-forecast) based on their availability and **back** or **front-end** role

Despite, we are unable to provide an accurate estimated time. That is why we want to adjust our project management:

- [**Estimate** *user stories* based on story points instead of hours](https://www.mountaingoatsoftware.com/blog/the-main-benefit-of-story-points)
- [**Estimate** no more *sub-tasks*, only the *user story*](https://youtu.be/sCCUEtjCpCs?t=1m26s)
- Switch to Trello or Jira instead of Redmine
- Planning to do more Scrum activities

  - Daily stand-up
  - Sprint review
  - **Estimate** story points for *user stories* with entire team

When we apply all this, we will most probably achieve a more accurate total **estimate** for a sprint and plan a feasible amount of work in a sprint based on the velocity.

We only have one problem. If we no longer use *sub-tasks* for the **estimation**, we also do not know how many hours a **back** or **front-end** developer needs to be scheduled in [Harvest Forecast](https://www.getharvest.com/forecast/harvest-and-forecast).

Hence the question: how to schedule **back** and **front-end** developers based on story points?

Related:

- [Why use story points instead of hours for estimating?](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/2765/why-use-story-points-instead-of-hours-for-estimating)
- [Why use both story points and hours?](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/15516/why-use-both-story-points-and-hours)
- [Best measurable units for non cross-functional team estimation](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/17600/best-measurable-units-for-non-cross-functional-team-estimation)
- [How to estimate accurate velocity when team members are on leave](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/8819/how-to-estimate-accurate-velocity-when-team-members-are-on-leave/17262#17262)

Comment: Schedule them for 40 hours a week each. Estimate projects in weeks times people, not task breakdowns. In short, be less granular to improve overall accuracy.

Comment: @ToddA.Jacobs thanks! But what if it turns out that it is 70% back and 30% front-end?

Comment: If you want the benefits of agile estimation, don't fall prey to the 100% utilization fallacy or do individual estimation. Estimate work *for the team as a whole.*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I've interpreted correctly, your Question is how to convert Story Point estimations for User Stories into time-estimations for each individual developer.

My answer?

**Don't.**

The only possible reason I can think for why you would *need* individual estimates is for individual KPIs (Key Performance Indicators). Which, in my experience, are themselves harmful.

Instead, you should estimate for the *Team*. Treat the Team as a cohesive whole. Rather than taking Developer F 1 day and Developer B 2 days, the story takes the Team 2 story points. (Which you can then convert to time estimates for the Team, as I believe has been answered here before).

From your comment:

> But what if it turns out that it is 70% back and 30% front-end?

This smells to me of the [100% Utilization Fallacy](https://dzone.com/articles/100-utilization-myth). So it turns out to take 70% back-end and 30% front-end... so what? That means the front-end developer(s) can spend more effective use of their slack time that Sprint. Maybe they can pair up with the back-end developer(s) in order to become [T-shaped](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T-shaped_skills).

Comment: Thanks, very enlightening! The reason is to use developers as efficiently as possible across multiple projects (in case of 70% back and 30% front-end) and so give the customer value for money, I could be wrong?

Comment: @BartvanKleef See the 100% utilization fallacy. You should be optimizing for throughput of tasks, not time of developers.

Comment: @BartvanKleef I’d caution against spreading the same person across multiple projects as well. There’s a huge cost to that kind of context switching and also inevitably ends with two projects fighting for 70% of the same person’a time. That results in a miserable workplace and burn out.

Comment: @BartvanKleef: What would you do if most projects are 70% back and 30% front for the next month? Send half your front-end developers with unpaid leave?

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau good question! We have some on-call (0-hours) employees. Or we place them on our own, side projects instead of customer. Never unpaid leave.

Comment: @RubberDuck this is precisely why we use Harvest Forecast. Schedule developers on a sprint based on their availability in consecutive days. In the example given both back and front-end developers will be scheduled for a second sprint (and so another project) later that same week (because there is extra back or front-end work). How else do we give the customer value for money?

Comment: @Sarov you got a good point there!

Comment: @BartvanKleef If you're scheduling developers on a sprint based on their availability and the work, you're not doing anything even related to Scrum, so calling it a sprint might just confuse people.

Answer (score 3):

An approach I have seen done successfully is as follows.

The team estimates each backlog item in story points. The whole team estimates and they agree on the story points figure based on relative sizing.

The story points *done* in previous sprints is used to calculate the velocity of the team. This provides a guide to the capacity of future sprints.

In the planning meeting the team pulls stories from the product backlog until they have reached their capacity. For example, if the team's velocity is 30 story points, they would add stories to the sprint backlog until they reach close to 30 story points.

Next, the team looks at the highest priority story in the sprint backlog and breaks it down in to technical tasks. They do hour-based estimates on the technical tasks and note if they require a specialisation (e.g. front-end developer or back-end developer).

The team then uses the same approach on each of the remaining stories on the sprint backlog. As they are doing this, the Scrum Master tracks the hours for each specialisation. If they notice that one specialisation is getting overloaded, they tell the team. At this point the team can either:

- Remove any stories from the sprint backlog that have not yet been broken down in to technical tasks
- Look at the top of the product backlog and see if there are stories they can swap in to the sprint that creates a better balance of work for the various specialisations

This ensures that no specialisation becomes overloaded in the sprint.

It is worth noting that a better long-term approach is to ensure that team members have [T shaped skills](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T-shaped_skills). If team members can do *both* front-end and back-end development work then they can:

- Be much more flexible with the types of stories they bring in to sprints
- Worry less about team members being under or over worked
- Spend less time estimating

Comment: Thanks for sharing! This seems to me the right approach to convert story points in estimations for user stories for back and front-end if you want to.